# Multiple Images - Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, video, image-processing

I have written a matlab project that takes a video as an input, cuts it into frames, and shows the frames to the user one by one, giving him the ability to make changes to each frame.

I want to add a "side bar", that shows a particular frame to the user, as well as buttons for GUI frames from 1 to 10, when he can press on "->" or "<-" to move to prev\next 10 frames, and can click on a frame to show it in a larger size.

Something like this:

```
   This is the GUI:
```

> ```
> .__________________________________.
> |                                  | 
> |          Frame No. i             | 
> |                                  | 
> |--------------------------------- | 
> |<-| Frame j|j+1|.....|Frame j+9|->| 
> |__________________________________|
> ```

I thought about using "subplot" but didn't know how to add the ability to show\update prev\next frames on clicking.

Another implementation is something like this:

```
% The Main Image:
   hAx = axes('Position',[0 0.3 1 0.8], 'Parent',hFig);
   hMainImg = imshow(img, 'Parent',hAx);

% the slider
hPanel = uipanel('Position',[0 0.04 1 0.26], 'Parent',hFig);
uicontrol('Style','slider', 'Parent',hFig, ...
    'Callback',@slider_callback, ...
    'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 0.04], ...
    'Value',1, 'Min',1, 'Max',mx, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./mx);
```

But then, what about the slider?

Any ideas how can I implement this?

Comment: How are the frames stored that you've cut from the video?

Comment: I read (cut) frames this way: im = read(video, i); And save all the 248 frames in a folder called "Frames"

Comment: What you're asking for is actually quite a bit of work.  You need to add multiple `axes` objects to your image, populate each one with an image, add two buttons, and setup appropriate callbacks on the buttons and subimages.  There's no quick function to do this.  You'll get better help if you ask a more specific question.  To answer this one would involve creating the widget for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. We open a small video file, and reads all its 141 frames. You can browse through them using the slider, click any small image to display it in the main axis.

```
function framesBrowserDemo()
    %# read all frames at once
    vid = VideoReader('xylophone.mpg');
    numImgs = get(vid, 'NumberOfFrames');
    frames = read(vid);
    clear vid

    %# design GUI
    numThumbs = 5;
    mx = numImgs-numThumbs+1;
    hFig = figure('Menubar','none');
    hPanel = uipanel('Position',[0 0.04 1 0.16], 'Parent',hFig);
    uicontrol('Style','slider', 'Parent',hFig, ...
        'Callback',@slider_callback, ...
        'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 0.04], ...
        'Value',1, 'Min',1, 'Max',mx, 'SliderStep',[1 10]./mx);

    %# main axis, and show first frame
    hAx = axes('Position',[0 0.2 1 0.8], 'Parent',hFig);
    hMainImg = imshow(frames(:,:,:,1), 'Parent',hAx);

    %# thumbnail axes
    hThumImg = zeros(numThumbs,1);
    for i=1:numThumbs
        %# create axis, show frame, hookup click callback
        hAx = axes('Parent',hPanel, ...
            'Position',[(i-1)/numThumbs 0 1/numThumbs 1]);
        hThumImg(i) = imshow(frames(:,:,:,i), 'Parent',hAx);
        set(hThumImg(i), 'ButtonDownFcn',@click_callback)
        axis(hAx, 'normal')
    end

    %# callback functions
    function slider_callback(src,~)
        val = round(get(src,'Value'));  %# starting index
        %# update the thumbnails
        for k=1:numel(hThumImg)
            set(hThumImg(k), 'CData',frames(:,:,:,k+val-1))
            drawnow
        end
    end

    function click_callback(src,~)
        %# update the main image
        set(hMainImg, 'CData',get(src,'CData'));
        drawnow
    end
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: First of all thanks alot for this great answer. I know its a little bit late, but I have couple of questions: When Im trying to run this on some video it shows me the following error: No enough memory. And the More Important, what if I already have frames saved in my computer? what should I change in the code? I tried to change the code and use existing frames it shows me: Function IMAGEDISPLAYPARSEINPUTS expected its first input, I,
to be one of these types:

  double, single, uint8, uint16, uint32, int8, int16, int32, logical

Instead its type was struct.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @HowaidaKhoureieh: To have a snappy UI, I read all the video frames in memory at the beginning. Obviously if you have a large video file, you will run out of memory (think of it as loading the entire uncompressed video). The alternative is to only read frames as needed, though scrolling will be slower. Now the same applies if you had existing separated frames saved as image files. Instead of extracting frames from the movie object (`VideoReader` in my code), you will have to read each image from disk (`imread`). It will be a lot easier if your frames were named according to their index. HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the videoioPlayer I posted to MatlabCentral. The player reads videos via the VIDEOIO-library from a file (*.avi, *.mov, *.mpeg, ...) frame by frame -- thus the videoio lib is quite memory efficient.

The videoioPlayer allows the user to jump through the video by keyinput (e.g. '+' go one frame further, 'CTRL +' jump 10 frames further, 'ALT +' advance 100 frames, 'SPACE' is start/pause/resume playing etc.)
In addition the videoioPlayer allows to plugin a (custom) filter function that is applied to each frame before being displayed. 
And the videoioPlayer can sync with other videoioPlayers in order to display 2 videos (e.g. the original and the processed video) simultaneously)

It would be possible to write a filter plugin (see the demo files of the videoioPlayer) that handles also your user input; so in case you manage to compile the videoiolibrary (straight forward under linux, a bit tricky for mac, never tried with windows but you need the VisualStudio for that) you can use the player directly for your task.

In case you don't want to use the videoiolib you could alter the player to use a different frame grabbing method or just try to understand the callback functions in the videoioplayer to get inspired for your project.

Here are the links:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoio/files/

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35119-videoioplayer

Answer (score 0):

You could define the layout using the subplot command:

http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html